# How can I get program changes in PHP script to appear immediately?

Tags: php, caching

This is probably completely obvious to somebody.

I'm using PHP on Windows 2008 Server R2 and IIS 7. FastCGI, PHP V5.3.

When I make a program change, I have to repeatedly change the file and re-save a good few times before the code recompiles and my edits are reflected. This is getting seriously annoying.

I've read about bytecode caching APC or Wincache etc. in the PHP manual, but as far as I can tell there is nothing installed.

Is there a standard bytecode cache? How do I disable it?

If not, what else could be causing this?

Thanks for your help.

P.S. IIS 7 Output caching is switched off (unticked) for both User and Kernel on this website instance.

Comment: PHP 5.5 has built-in opcode cache... You should also tell us which version you are using!

Comment: He is using PHP 5.3, look at the end of the second sentence.

Comment: @Rain Nah, it's parser just outputs straight bytecode. So about that AST...

Comment: There is no reason why a PHP file would be cached in the way you're saying it is. The only time when a PHP script doesn't get re-parsed is when you use APC and have apc.stat variable set to 0, which means the server always pulls bytecode cache from APC's memory. What *seems* to be the case here is that you have your browser caching older data. In order to track the bug, you have to ensure that it isn't the browser doing the caching. So, every time you do a refresh, just make sure you empty the cache. If you still get the same content even after edits - then it's something else.

Comment: @RainFromHeaven - may I suggest creating a blog where you'll post your thoughts or feelings? This is a problem solving website and a person here has a problem. If you don't have anything constructive to say, please move on and be sarcastic / witty somewhere else, it's really immature of you to behave this way.

Comment: Sorry, sorry, I'll keep that in mind. Deleted previous comments.

Comment: This is definitely not browser cache. If I change data in the database, the page is recalculated.